# Ansible: include_role on a loop running unexpected number of times

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I am trying to use include_role with items

```
---
- hosts: cluster
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Execute test role
        include_role:
          name: testrole
        with_items:
        - 'one'
...
```

My role is

```
---
- name: Just debugging
  debug:
...
```

The issue is that it seems that the role is being ran by each host X times per item where X is the number of hosts.

```
PLAY [cluster] *****************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [thisNode]
ok: [dww]

TASK [Execute test role] *******************************************************

TASK [testrole : Just debugging] ***********************************************
ok: [thisNode] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [dww] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

TASK [testrole : Just debugging] ***********************************************
ok: [thisNode] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [dww] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
dww                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
thisNode                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Ansible hosts:

```
[cluster]
thisNode ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local
dww
```

---

I cannot delegate the task because, in the real role, the task must be executed in each of the hosts.

Using `allow_duplicates: no` still outputs the same.

```
---
- hosts: cluster
  tasks:
    - name: Execute test role
      include_role:
        name: testrole
        allow_duplicates: False
      with_items:
      - 'one'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add `allow_duplicates: false` to prevent Ansible from running the same role twice with the same parameters.

---

Clearly the module is looped twice: once with hosts, the other time with the specified items. As it is supposed to runs the action against all hosts, the outer loop gets executed twice.

It's a new module in preview state and this behaviour should probably be files as an issue.

Ansible has an internal parameter `BYPASS_HOST_LOOP` to avoid such situations and this mechanism should probably be used by this module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It seems that neither workaround does it for me... I will edit the original post with the results of both workarounds

Comment: It's strange, because I tested `allow_duplicates: false` with your playbook and it did work. So it looks like you are not showing everything.

Comment: Maybe I am adding it to the wrong place. Where should I add it?

Comment: The block was for a rescue (in the real role). I am, however, just using this mock role to test. BTW, my role is in /etc/ansible/roles/testrole/tasks/main.yml ; how are you running your role?

Comment: Yes, I am running the role and `allow_duplicates: false` does change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `allow_duplicates: False` did not change anything. 
It seems that setting `serial: 1` on the play and it somehow solved it. This is a workaround that probably will work for a small number of hosts.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I already raised a ticket for it anyways on ansible's repository: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21279